# What does regular expression [A-Z]{2,3}\\d+ mean

Tags: regex

What does the regex `[A-Z]{0,2,3}\\d+` mean?

Does it match strings like

`AAA1234` 
`0000123`
`AA12345`

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean [`[A-Z]{0,3}\\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/6K8Txf/1)?`{0,3}` will match and uppercase character 0 - 3 times.

Comment: [Reference Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/335858)

Comment: www.regex101.com

Comment: Long story short, your regex would match `A{0,2,3}1234` strings ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/lga72J/1)).

Comment: You may find the [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fdoCIc/1) online tool beneficial to try this out yourself, and play around with regular expressions. Just put the regex in the top and not only will it explain what each part does when you hover, but it will let you try different input strings below to see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Not really, it would match `A{0,2,3}\ddd`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[A-Z]{0,2,3}\\d+
```

That looks like a typo.

`{}` braces shouldn't have more than two numbers in it.

`[A-Z]{0,3}` mean any alphabet between A and Z (capital) can occur 0 to 3 times.

And `\d+` means any digit (0-9) can occur 1 or more times.

That is the reason `[A-Z]{0,3}\d+` matches `AAA1234`, `0000123` and `AA12345`

Comment: OP's syntax is valid and compiles fine. The OP's regex matches the input string `A{0,2,3}1`. It is true that it's likely a typo, however.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense yes the {} was wrong it should have been [A-Z]{2,3}\\d+, I had to add another exception for only characters so my new string looks like:
[A-Z]{2,3}\\d+|\\d{7}
which has 2 or 3 characters in caps, with lagging digits or digits which are limited to 7

Comment: right, ggorlen...
Adjusted my answer

Comment: The backslash before the `d` is escaped, so it doesn't mean a digit... right?

Comment: In `[A-Z]{2,3}\d+|\d{7}`, with regards to `lagging digits or digits which are limited to 7 `;

`\d+` is a subset of `\d{7}`; i.e.: anything matched by `\d{7}` will also be matched by `\d+`. This makes `\d{7}` redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex (`[A-Z]{2,3}\\d+`) will match

- Two or three letters A-Z,
- followed by a backslash "\",
- and finally one or more instances of the letter "d".

Comment: @Uska Please use the `edit` button underneath your question to correct the mistake you made so that it is clear what you are asking.

Comment: Done, thanks for the clarification everyone.

Comment: The backslash is just escapted

Comment: @YassinHajaj I covered that in my answer, what else do you mean?

Comment: @CallumWatkins What I mean is that it will NOT match a backslash since the backslash is just used to escape the second one.

Comment: @YassinHajaj but... it will. If there is a mistake in the question that is not my problem.

Comment: @CallumWatkins Indeed you're right.. But it would have been a plus to correct it.. Since OP has provided some samples

Comment: @YassinHajaj the samples given are not what the regex *should* match, but OP's original thought of what the regex *might* match. I'm simply stating the facts, rather than answering a question that was not asked.